# How do I stop froala editor from automatically uploading image upon insert?

Tags: froala

Right now,it is uploading the image to their server,which is of course temporary.But,I don't want to upload it.I just want to insert as a blob or a base64 encoded string,and when the user actually presses the save button,it will get uploaded to my s3 bucket.Is something like that possible with froala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a hidden input field and a custom button to solve this problem.On clicking,the button triggers the click event on the hidden input field.I got the file from an onchange event,converted it to a objecturl and used image.insert.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your own answer as accepted if you solved your issue so that other people don't come here and try to solve it for you :)